# MySQL query to search only a section of a table

Tags: mysql

I want to optimize how records are searched in a system am developing using MySQL. If I have a table with 10,000 records, what sort of query can I write which will only search the first 500 records (that is, search that section of the table) and return the results available regardless of whether any rows matching the search criteria have been found.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: "return the results available regardless of whether any rows matching the search criteria have been found." This is a contradiction. Either you want the first 500 records that fit the criteria, or the first 500 in general.

Comment: I want the search to be limited to the latest 500 entries and not search elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using forced indices on the table? try https://www.howtoforge.com/when-to-use-indexes-in-mysql-databases

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.